# How to import Comodo certificates into Keystore?

Tags: tls, certificate-authority, openssl, java, cipher-selection

I'm trying to create a `Keystore`. I've already generated a Private Key, generated and sent a certificate request to a CA (Comodo), and I've received a ZIP file from the CA (Comodo) containing four certificates, `CRT` files.

The contents of the folder where as such:

```
   -example_domain.crt
   -COMODORSADomain ValidationSecureServerCA.crt
   -COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
   -AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
```

So I created a bundle `CRT`, where I concatenated all the certificates into a single `CRT` file, in this order:

```
 cat example_domain.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt COMODORSADomain ValidationSecureServerCA.crt > ssl-bundle.crt
```

I was able to use this bundle just fine for a Web Service. Now I'm migrating to another service that uses `Keystore P12` files. So I took the same bundle and created a `JKS Keystore` file, and then converted it to `P12`.

```
$ keytool -importcert \
        -trustcacerts -file example_domain.crt \
        -alias domain \
        -keystore keystore.jks

$ keytool -importkeystore \
-srckeystore keystore.jks \
-srcalias example.domain.com \
-destkeystore keystore.p12 \
-deststoretype PKCS12
```

The problem is that that this configuration doesn't work.
I'm getting the following error:

```
sys::IOErr: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
```

Does anybody know why? I know it's not my web service. I think it's the way I'm creating my `Keystore` file.

Comment: You need a PKCS12 containing the PRIVATE KEY AND the cert(s) (preferably the full chain, optionally excluding the root). You don't say where/how you generated the privatekey. If it was in a JKS file (probably with keytool) then 'import' the cert chain to *that* entry of *that* JKS, then convert *that* entry of *that* JKS to PKCS12 with keytool. If you generated the privatekey with openssl in a separate "PEM" file, use openssl to "export" the privatekey (file) *and* the certs (files) to pkcs12 (together).